# Switch correctly on reducer style payloads in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I currently have two types of data, `GenArtWorkerMsg` and `VehicleWorkerMsg`. I also have a Searcher that takes parts of those data-sets, but I cannot make the searcher understand which data-set has been passed, despite having a unique `type` property on the payload.

How do I force it to distinguish between the different payloads ?

[Typescript Playground with how I solved it so far](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2BBATsA6ge2QawsgsgM4DmUAvFAN4BQAkBAB7DICGAXFAOTwsC2EhTlAA%20XACYCAxoIDcdMS2DsohZgEt4xANoBdObVCQOnAG4QAFmskAbCDGQYArmFnUAvnOqHoANQtXbTBw8IlIKGnomVmNJFmQAOT4IIVFOWOR7JzBOfQUlDnhHXgAjPF19b2NiBDwrFGAAgRz3T28oAGUIOMlzREkGjHhCcio6avhayXrGwg44JFQg3AISfTNLGzsHZ1moPw3ArGXQuQ9qL3BoTu7zABVLgB42xmAEMWHcEAwAMw6u5B6fQGQwAfCMIq9kLwAPpqMQFIqlZD6awsTSw94IkplPTyRQsADyAHcJsgONcAb1%20mpBoQtN4dFpOHkWJxGYVschcZFmMoKYDqbT6ZdGZwXqw2RVLhxvPpHI44RxVMgNMQKqwhqjgYQAPxK9Sacotc5tW4awhAmnwcF0SpcSQYXhgWyvMT88zNWhgFggawYFjwv43e6QB6ccaTaabQQiLjrRqZHacEGnc4OobAKD8QiEFjVAASaLEtmQIwAFCxBfAOGa0RaqwBKchgmh0QhEtTAHpQCtVgB03t9-rEfe8TYitFihGg4ZqKqmqBmnDYdFotAna4A9JuoETzIooABJKB8KBiDCqqCSRzIZAIYDWECrtfp1RUKDyuEAGjP%20OJpJ-XlNUUK1CB-cUWEAy4oDcEZK2BAcfT9AMT2Gd0QwgJ5Lh%20E9%200HZCR28FNqCgUiyPIiioG3KA0E7cwnEzFhrGsKAABYoAgqBvVYXgwJUejHGsMQoEGR8oFKKBgCJDASMouTSNfDBbD7P1iDLCCG1k%20TKOo-DhygNRhnmeolhCEhY32RpTJWYgfwkQgwE7aBRKfbS5Oo4BzGgYzFiOMzSBZKB9xMS9POgNocNnUk6kXaNOC07S3ASpK3CAA)

```
type GenArtWorkerMsg = {
    extra: 'names' | 'descs';
    data: LoadTableReturn['2'];
    type: 'vehicleGroups';
};

type VehicleWorkerMsg = {
    extra: 'carName' | 'carGroup';
    data: LoadTableReturn['3'];
    type: 'genericArticles';
};

type SearchActions = {
    genericArticles: GenArtWorkerMsg;
    vehicleGroups: VehicleWorkerMsg;
};

type SearchType<type extends keyof SearchActions> = {
    term_id: number;
    lang_ids: number[];
    dataOwner: SearchActions[type]['data'][number];
    extra: SearchActions[type]['extra'];
    type: type;
    uuid: string;
    translations?: translations[];
};

type TransAction = {
    type: 'completedSearch';
    payload: SearchType<'genericArticles' | 'vehicleGroups'>;
}

const messageHandler = (action: TransAction) => {
    const { uuid, dataOwner, translations, extra, type } = action.payload;

    switch (action.payload.type) {
        case 'genericArticles':
            {
                // payload is GenArtWorkerMsg | VehicleWorkerMsg, despite only
                // the GenArtWorkerMsg data having the type of 'genericArticles'
```

Comment: `payload: SearchType<'genericArticles'> | SearchType<'vehicleGroups'>;`

Comment: @iz_ Thanks, missed that completely ! If you put that in an answer I'll mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially need to "lift" the union one level up, from the generic parameter into the type definition itself. TypeScript can only really narrow the union if it is at the highest level, not nested within a generic parameter.

Therefore, you need to do:

```
type TransAction = {
    type: 'completedSearch';
    payload: SearchType<'genericArticles'> | SearchType<'vehicleGroups'>;
}
```